# Split numeric variables by decimals in R

Tags: r, split, character, decimal, numeric

I have a data frame with a column that contains numeric values, which represent the price.

| ID | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 1124 | 12.34 |
| 1232 | 12.01 |
| 1235 | 13.10 |

I want to split the column Total by "." and create 2 new columns with the euro and cent amount. Like this:

| ID | Total | Euro | Cent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1124 | 12.34 | 12 | 34 |
| 1232 | 12.01 | 12 | 01 |
| 1235 | 13.10 | 13 | 10 |
| 1225 | 13.00 | 13 | 00 |

The euro and cent column should also be numeric.

I tried:

```
df[c('Euro', 'Cent')] <- str_split_fixed(df$Total, "(\\.)", 2)
```

But I get 2 new columns of type character that looks like this:

| ID | Total | Euro | Cent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1124 | 12.34 | 12 | 34 |
| 1232 | 12.01 | 12 | 01 |
| 1235 | 13.10 | 13 | 1 |
| 1225 | 13.00 | 13 |  |

If I convert the character columns (euro and cent) to numeric like this:
as.numeric(df$Euro)
the 00 cent value turns into NULL and the 10 cent turn into 1 cent.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Two methods:

1. If `class(dat$Total)` is `numeric`, you can do this:

   ```r
   dat <- transform(dat, Euro = Total %/% 1, Cent = 100 * (Total %% 1))
   dat
   #     ID Total Euro Cent
   # 1 1124 12.34   12   34
   # 2 1232 12.01   12    1
   # 3 1235 13.10   13   10
   ```

   `%/%` is the integer-division operator, `%%` the modulus operator.
2. If `class(dat$Total)` is `character`, then

   ```r
   dat <- transform(dat, Euro = sub("\\..*", "", Total), Cent = sub(".*\\.", "", Total))
   dat
   #     ID Total Euro Cent
   # 1 1124 12.34   12   34
   # 2 1232 12.01   12   01
   # 3 1235 13.10   13   10
   ```

   The two new columns are also `character`. For this, you may want one of two more steps:

   1. Removing leading `0`s, and keep them `character`:

      ```r
      dat[,c("Euro", "Cent")] <- lapply(dat[,c("Euro", "Cent")], sub, pattern = "^0+", replacement = "")
      dat
      #     ID Total Euro Cent
      # 1 1124 12.34   12   34
      # 2 1232 12.01   12    1
      # 3 1235 13.10   13   10
      ```
   2. Convert to numbers:

      ```r
      dat[,c("Euro", "Cent")] <- lapply(dat[,c("Euro", "Cent")], as.numeric)
      dat
      #     ID Total Euro Cent
      # 1 1124 12.34   12   34
      # 2 1232 12.01   12    1
      # 3 1235 13.10   13   10
      ```

   (You can also use `as.integer` if you know both columns will always be such.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use standard numeric functions:

```r
df$Euro <- floor(df$Total)
df$Cent <- df$Total %% 1 * 100
```